# Avoiding onChange on ComboBox when chaning selection dynamically

Tags: dojo

I have a combobox for which I have a validation that a change in selection should be reverted back on meeting a condition.

I have detected the condition but when I change the value and displayedValue of combobox, the onChange associated with the combobox gets fired. Following is the code I am using to change the selection:

```
dijit.byId('scheduleName').set('value',val,false);
dijit.byId('scheduleName').set('displayedValue',displayVal,false);
```

I have also tried to set the onChange to blank before firing above code and then re attaching the onChange code as below:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('scheduleName'),'onChange','');
dijit.byId('scheduleName').set('value',scheduleNameVal,false);
dijit.byId('scheduleName').set('displayedValue',trim(String(scheduleNameName)),false);
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('scheduleName'),'onChange', "hideGrid");
```

hideGrid is a javascript function. I am using Dojo 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dojo.disconnect` instead of

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('scheduleName'),'onChange','');
```

Example:

```
var hndl, sched = dijit.byId('scheduleName');
var fnWireOnChange = function(){
  hndl = dojo.connect(sched,'onChange', 'hideGrid');
};

dojo.disconnect(hndl);
sched.set('value',scheduleNameVal,false);
sched.set('displayedValue',trim(String(scheduleNameName)),false);
fnWireOnChange();
```

As a side note, `connect/disconnect` has been deprecated in favor of `dojo/on`

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html#dojo-on

Comment: works well, but after calling fnWireOnChange(), the cursor is present inside the comobox for typing. Now if I click outside the combobox, onchange gets fired. How to avoid the presence of cursor inside combobox. I tried using document.getElmentById('someotheid').focus() but wasn't successful. I am using FilteringSelect and not ComboBox

Answer (score 3):

Set only *value*, not *displayedValue*

```
myComboBox.set("value", value, false);
```

then only `watch` callback is fired, not `dojo/on` or `onChange`.

Check this jsFiddle out to see differencies: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/d7ymY/

Note: If you need to `trim()` *displayedValue* consider a custom [`setter`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/Stateful#custom-accessors) or `dojo/aspect::before`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I am struggling on combo box onChange event firing on every dynamic change. Thanks yaar